# How to force text to appear after a table?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    ~                 & Horns rev 1 & Horns rev 2 & Anholt \\ \hline
    Antal møller      & 80   & 90 & 111    \\ \hline
    Effekt pr. mølle  & 2 MW   & 2.3 MW  & 3.6 MW \\ \hline
    Areal             & 20km$^2$ & 33km$^2$  & 88km$^2$      \\ \hline
    Samlede effekt    & 160MW  & 209MW & 400MW \\ \hline
    Effekt pr. areal  & 0.008 MW/m$^2$ & 0,0063 MW/m$^2$ & 0,0045 MW/m$^2$ \\ \hline
    Km kabel          & 55  & 72  & 185 \\ \hline
    kWh-pris          & 48 øre & 51.8 øre  & 105.1 øre\\ \hline
    Pris (mia. kr.)   & 2  & 3.5 & 9     \\ \hline
    Rotordiameter     & 80 meter & 93 meter  & 120 meter \\ \hline
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
        \makebox (16,40)[t]{Formation} & \raisebox{0mm}[42mm][1mm] {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Horns_rev_1.png}}
    & {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Horns_rev_2.png}}  &
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Anholt.png}}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}


\end{table}

"I want my text to appear down here"
```

Comment: Well, after I've made your code compilable, the text does appear after the table.

Comment: So your table is made to float. Do you want the text to stay with the float, even if you have other textual content around it? Almost like a "footnote to the table"?

Comment: The text was just an example, there is supposed to be more, but then some of the text is over the table and the rest is under

Comment: Is putting the text before the `\end{table}` good enough for you?